# Infimum w.r.t. to one variable for a multivariate function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a partially ordered set of smooth functions $f(x),x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying
$$
   1 \leq f(x) \leq Cg(x), 
$$
for some $C>0$ and a fixed $g(x)$ in $\mathcal{A}$.
Suppose I introduce a parameter $t$. That is consider function $f(t,x)$ which is continuous in $t \in [0,T],T>0$ and is valued in $\mathcal{A}$. I want to know what are the properties of
$$
   \tilde{f}(x) =\inf_{t \in [0,T]} \; f(t,x).
$$
Will it be smooth always? One thing I know is it is measurable. What would be nature of $\tilde{f}(x)$?

Comment: Not necessarily. Think of $f(t,x)=(t-1)x$ on $t\in[0,2]$.

Comment: @Chrystomath Note that $f(t,x)$ needs to be in the class. That is it must be greater than 1.

Comment: You get the idea. The infimum could get a corner by varying $t$. Smoothness is a local property, so you can take the example and extend it smoothly as you wish. Actually take $f(t,x)=2+\tanh(t-1)x$.